Regex config fail2ban for multiline modsecurity
I'm trying to improve fail2ban configuration for modsecurity in nginx so that regex-expression covers the whole block, is without maxline and finally gives more accurate triggering. Made a regex and it works fine on regex101.com. However, when I try to use it in the config for fail2ban it finds nothing.
Old regex
^\[\S+ \S+\] \S+ ?(?:<IP6>|<IP4>) \S+ \S+ \S+\n[\s\S]*\n---([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})---F--\nHTTP\/[0-9]\.[0-9] ?(403|429)\s

New regex
---[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}---A--\n\[\d{2}\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \S+\] \d+\.\d+ ?(?:<IP6>|<IP4>) \d{2,5} ((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}) \d{2,5}\n(.*\n){1,}?HTTP\/(1|2)\.(1|0) ?(403|429)(.*\n){1,}?---[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}---Z--

fail2ban's filter config
[Definition]
datepattern = ^\[%%d/%%m/%%Y:%%H:%%M:%%S\s
failregex = ^---[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}---A--\n\[\d{2}\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \S+\] \d+\.\d+ ?(?:<IP6>|<IP4>) \d{2,5} ((\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}|([0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}:){1,7}[0-9a-fA-F]{0,4}) \d{2,5}\n(.*\n){1,}?HTTP\/(1|2)\.(1|0) ?(403|429)(.*\n){1,}?---[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}---Z--

ignoreregex =

fail2ban version: 0.11.2
The logic is simple, if a client’s IP gets into modsec_audit.log with a 403 or 429 error and checks in there a certain number of times, then he will be banned.
That's all

You didn't mention what fail2ban version you use, I think it depends on it too.
Btw seems like you made the new regex for your ModSecurity's audit log, not the Nginx's error.log. I'm not sure about that's a good idea, I always prefer to check the error.log.
Also in your regex you use the audit log's section A, which is the request status line and client IP. But this means if a request appears in audit.log, you will count it as an attack (by fail2ban).
If you share some information about your aims, I try to help you.

Well, yes. The fail2ban's filter implies exactly this log. This is where information about attackers is dumped.
The filter does not work on everyone. Only for 403 and 429 errors. In the modsec config, rules have also been added for actions that do not appear in the modsec_audit log.
I writed about this and logic of work in first post.
